# Is there a limit to the number of user I can share a Big Query Dataset with?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Similarly, is there a limit to the number of user I can add to a GCP project?

Comment: This is not a development question really.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The answer can probably be found in their docs. Instinctively I don't see why there would be a limit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good experience with adding few thousands of users for both dataset and project - there is no issue.
Only one thing I would recommend DO NOT ADD users directly to dataset/project - use google groups as umbrella - much easier to manage going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Literally there is no limit on the number of users you can add to your GCP project or share your BigQuery dataset with.